# MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER is not thrown each time I moving mouse over button

Tags: flash, events

I'm having button (class that extends `Sprite`). In the middle of button there's an icon (`Sprite` with attached icon). Sometimes (not always!) when mouse enters button, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` is not thrown. When mouse enters icon `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` is always thrown. What is the reason of such strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a `hitClip` sprite (with alpha aet to 0) to `button` sprite. As it written in [livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3amouseOver)

> The mouseOver event is dispatched each time the mouse enters the area
>   of any child object of the display object container

So to get `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` one need to have something under mouse (e.g. transparent clip)